# ¿Como aplicar correctamente la función password_verify, para loguear usuarios, empleando 2 variables sesion, para usuarios diferentes?

Tags: php, mysqli

```js
//FUNCIONES LLAMADAS
//intentaba en esta función loguear dos tipos de usuario de la bd,
//se diferencia si es admin o usuario un campo "admin" de tipo  tinyint(2) 
//1 para admin, 0 para usuario. las passwords están cifradas con hash, 
//pero no logró loguearlos. 

function validarUser($usuario, $clave)
   {
     global $connect;
     $consulta = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (User='".$usuario."' OR EMail='".$usuario."') AND Password='".$clave."'";

     $respuesta = mysqli_query($connect, $consulta);

     if( $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($respuesta) )  //extrae la primera fila
     {
      if (password_verify($clave,$fila[3])) {  //comparando lo ingresado en input con el valor del campo password en bd
      session_start();  //habilita uso de sesiones
      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
      $_SESSION['admin'] = $fila[5];  //crea variable de sesion llamado admin, asignandole el valor del campo en bd
      
      return true;
       }  //cierre paswd verify
     }  //cierra fetch_row
     return false;

   }

    function haIniciadoSesion()
   {
      session_start();
      return isset( $_SESSION['usuario'] );  //preguntamos si ha sido asignado valor a ña variable
      //Retorna true en caso de tener valor la variable

   }


   function esAdmin()
   {
       
      return $_SESSION['admin'];
   }
```

```html
<?php
//ARCHIVO PHP QUE RECIBE LOS DATOS DE USUARIO DEL FORM HTML
//Y LLAMA A LAS FUNCIONES DE VALIDAR DE UN ARCHIVO EXTERNO

  require '../Model/Model_Depto.php';
  $connect =  conectar(); //conexion a bd

  $usuario = $_POST['user'];
  $clave =  $_POST['pass'];


  if( validarUser($usuario, $clave) ) {
    //acceediendo
        if(esAdmin())
          header('Location: ../View/index_depto1.php');
    else header('Location: ../View/index_depto2.php');  //direccion
  } else {
    //si no regresamos al formulario inicial
  

?>

   <script>
   alert('DATOS INCORRECTOS: NO SE PUDO IDENTIFICAR USUARIO')
   location.href = "../View/login_depto.html"; 
   </script>

<?php
   desconectar();
}

?>
```

Comment: Una consulta... Tu haces un select * User where user = user y password = clave... Si esto te responde ALGO, porque verificas la contraseña? teniendo en cuenta que tu consulta valida que la contraseña sea la misma que esta en la bd?

Comment: están encriptadas las contraaseñas con password_hash(). intentaba hacer login con el usuario y verificando el password en hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta deberia ser

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (User='".$usuario."' OR EMail='".$usuario."')";
$respuesta = mysqli_query($connect, $consulta);

if( $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($respuesta) )  //extrae la primera fila
{
   if (password_verify($clave,$fila[3])) {
        session_start();  //habilita uso de sesiones
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $fila[5];  //crea variable de sesion llamado admin, asignandole el valor del campo en bd
   }
}
```

¿por que cambiar la consulta? Porque tu estabas buscando en tu tabla users uno que coincidiera con

- User fuera igual **O** Email sea igual
- **Y** password (que esta encriptada con `password_hash` fuera igual al input password que NO esta encriptado, por lo tanto jamas ibas a tener resultado.

Por otro lado si traer al usuario que coincida el User o Email (que me imagino que esos valores son unicos) tendrias al posible Usuario y con `password_verify` sabrias si realmente es el usuario puesto que su password deberia coincidir.

Comment: tiene mucha razón ya entendi, muchas gracias por la atención, saludos

Comment: saludos @ArmandoArellano